# Extraction of contour positions and orientations of an image

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

I'm basically following a paper, " Using a statistical language model to improve the performance of an HMM-based cursive handwriting recognition system".

Here the author has extracted a vector of 9 features from each sliding window. quoting the paper:

> The first three features are the weight of the window, its centre of
>   gravity and the second order moment of the window.
>
> Features four and five define the position of the upper and lower
>   contour in the window, features six and seven give the orientation of
>   the upper and lower contour by the gradient of the contour at the
>   windows position, feature eight gives the number of black to white
>   transitions in vertical direction, while feature nine gives the number
>   of black pixels between the upper and lower contour.

I managed to calculate the first three features the paper is talking about, but I seem to have trouble understanding the features 4,5,6,7,8.

I can calculate the contour of an image. Suppose, this is a window of one of the text lines(windows is of length 14 pixels, as suggested by paper):

[image]

And this is the extracted contour of the image:

[image]

So what exactly is the upper and lower contour here? from where can I consider the limits, if it refers to the top and bottom pixels then I could have extracted those without contour extraction? Similarly the orientation of these contours is equally confusing.

I would really appreciate some guidance here.

Comment: The images are not visible. Please modify them.

Comment: @NKN I tried it on different browsers and the images are working for me. Can you please try again

Comment: this is how I see the images, maybe the whole image should be like this, I do not have any idea. http://pasteboard.co/26C6SF7U.png

Comment: @NKN I belive that's how it's supposed to be. Op is not showing the full image but only the 14 pixel sliding window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave a look at the paper, and I am pretty sure that "upper" and "lower" should be read as "uppest" and "lowest". This especially makes sense as the authors have a special focus on the preprocessing of their data that they normalize in both the horizontal and vertical directions. They take care to have a kind of robustness to scale, writing angle,...

I guess that features 4 and 5 can be the extremal ordinates of the contours, which, combined with features 6 & 7 which are the gradients = orientations, give a good idea of the shape of these parts of the contour.

Feature 9, will be mostly useful to make the difference between letters that can have similar vertical shapes I guess, such as "i", "l", "j".

This is my understanding. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Yes, I have done the pre-processing mentioned in the paper. So the upset and lowest values is the upper most pixel and lower most pixel? If that is the case, couldn't I have acquired those from the original black and white image? Why  did I have to get the contour of the image?

Comment: I think contours are useful for 2 reasons:
- They insure there is no artifact in the image (= isolated noise pixel) which could induce erroneous features values
- They normalize the feature 9 which " gives the number of black pixels between the upper and lower contour". Using the contours allow to actually detect the number of b/w transitions. So "l" will have no transition, but "i" will have 2 due to the dot. "s" will have 4. It's another discriminant between letters.

This 9th feature makes only sense if you use black contours on a white background. (opposite to the image in your 1st post)